# When will the last ADA be 'mined'

Tags: supply

How long until all ada is in circulation? I.e. when will Cardanos circulating supply be 45 billion ada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around 2043 the reserve supply will drop below 100 million, meaning most will be in circulation around 2040. Around 2140 the whole reserve supply will be dried up.

You could calculate this yourself, by applying the current monetary policy:

> Calculating the 'reserve half life' (that is, the time that it takes
> for half of the reserve to be used up) visualizes the impact of
> choosing a specific value of ρ over another. This was the subject of
> much discussion, and eventually, the value assigned was 0.3%. The
> reason why is that mathematical projections showed that a ρ (the fixed
> percentage of ada going into the virtual pot every epoch) value of
> 0.3% would mean a reserve half-life of four to five years. In simple terms, just half of the remaining reserve would be used every four to
> five years.
>
> https://docs.cardano.org/explore-cardano/monetary-policy

Other reads:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adanomics-cardano-ada-supply-reserves-rewards-komarovskiy-mba/